# Reuse parallel stage in declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a declarative Jenkins pipeline which contains several identical stages running in parallel. I would like to reuse these sections, however so far the best I've been able to achieve is as follows:

```
stage('Deploy & E2E') {
    parallel {
        stage('E2E 1') {
            agent { ... }
            environment { ... }
            steps {
                script { runE2ESteps() }
            }
            post { ... }
        }
        stage('E2E 2') {
            agent { ... }
            environment { ... }
            steps {
                script { runE2ESteps() }
            }
            post { ... }
        }
        stage('Other unrelated stage, not wanting reuse') {
            agent { ... }
            environment { ... }
            steps {
                // something else
            }
            post { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to *partially* reuse bits, by extracting the steps out into a method, but there is still quite a bit of duplication in the `agent`, `environment` and `post` blocks. Ideally I want to write something like:

```
stage('Deploy & E2E') {
    parallel {
        script {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                stage('E2E ${i}') {
                    agent { ... }
                    environment { ... }
                    steps { ... }
                    post { ... }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Other unrelated stage, not wanting reuse') {
            agent { ... }
            environment { ... }
            steps {
                // something else
            }
            post { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

But apparently I can't do this in declarative land - Jenkins seems very finicky about what precisely you're allowed to have at various points in the file.

I've tried a few other approaches, too, but none of them have worked:

- Using `matrix` for the E2E block seemed promising, but you're not allowed to nest `matrix` within `parallel` so this didn't pan out (because there are other, unrelated stages we want running in parallel to the E2E steps)
- Using the in-line `parallel` command. This doesn't achieve what I want because I need each stage running in its own agent (not parallelised within the same agent).

I've attached a diagram of what the pipeline looks like - it's behaving exactly as I want right now, just with more code duplication than I'd like. If we want to change the parallelism of our E2E, it currently involves copy+pasting or removing a block of code, rather than (ideally) changing one number somewhere.

Maybe this just isn't possible, but I figured I might as well chuck out a post to see if there are any ideas that I missed.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never found a solution to this in Jenkins. In the end, we've moved to Github Actions where this is possible with a matrix job.

Answer (score 0):

```
stage('Deploy & E2E') {
    parallel {
        script {
        stage('Other unrelated stage, not wanting reuse') {
            agent { ... }
            environment { ... }
            steps {
                // something else
            }
            post { ... }
        }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                stage('E2E ${i}') {
                    agent { ... }
                    environment { ... }
                    steps { ... }
                    post { ... }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

have a try

Comment: Nah, sadly this runs into the same issue my approach encountered:

`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

WorkflowScript: 364: Expected a stage @ line 364, column 17.

                   script {

                   ^


WorkflowScript: 363: No stages specified @ line 363, column 13.

               parallel {

               ^


WorkflowScript: 363: No stages specified @ line 363, column 13.

               parallel {

               ^
`

It seems you can't have `script` inside `parallel` :(